# What is the term for the electricity, floor tiles, etc in a house or office? Like when you can't move in yet because those things are still lacking

Tags: proper-nouns

What is the term for the electricity, floor tiles, etc in a house or office? Like, when you can't move in yet because those things are still lacking. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK at least, the building trade term is [**finishings**](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/finishing?family=finishings) although the dictionaries are generally not very supportive of this.

As for the electrical work, that is done in two stages, "first fix" (the hidden work) and "second fix" (the fittings and fixtures).

So you could say

> I can't move in because the **fittings and fixtures** are incomplete.

Comment: "fixtures and fittings" is the right phrase. I'm not sure about "finishings"

Comment: @JamesK the term [finishings](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/finishing+trades) includes the tiling mentioned in the question. It's used in the building trade.